# Why glDrawArrays doesn't draw with OpenGL on mac

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I'm new to OpenGL and I can't figure out why nothing is displayed in the window. I'm using Mavericks (OS X 10.9.5) and there should be something missing I guess

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>
#include "FirstTriangleExample.h"

static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};

GLuint vertexbuffer;
GLuint VertexArrayID;

void FirstTriangleExample::init() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(VertexArrayID);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

// called in loop
void FirstTriangleExample::update() {
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glFlush();
}

void FirstTriangleExample::dispose() {
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArraysAPPLE(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glDeleteProgram(programID);
}
```

with the example below everything works fine(I see the red square)

```
#include "RedSquareExample.h"
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>

void RedSquareExample::init() {}

void RedSquareExample::update() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f);
    glVertex2f( 0.5f,  0.5f);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f,  0.5f);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void RedSquareExample::dispose() {}
```

Maybe the problem is in using APPLE extension (`glGenVertexArraysAPPLE()` and `glBindVertexArrayAPPLE()`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see from your code, you are using the fixed function pipeline. But this code:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
```

is only supposed to work when using shaders. In case of fixed function, you might want to use something like

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)0);
```

In addition, you are not using the VAO correctly. The purpose of a VAO is to store the bindings of buffers to attributes, but you reset the binding in your update method anyhow.

Comment: You've worded it better than me and covered more. Have a +1 :-)

Comment: @Peregrin: Your welcome. Feel free to accept the answer.